# Define different batch sizes in spring data jpa for different repositories

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 different repositories in the same Spring Boot project.

I would like to define different batch sizes for the 2 different repositories. However, I could not find any solution for Spring Data Jpa config.

The repositories are given below:

```java
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, String> {
   Page<Item> findItemByCreationDateBefore(Timestamp creationDate, Pageable pageable);
}


@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, String> {
   @Query("SELECT c FROM Car c WHERE c.journeyCode = :journeyCode " +
          "AND c.currentLocationId = :currentLocationId")
   Page<Delivery> findCars(Long journeyCode, Long currentLocationId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

The batch size configuration is given below

```
    jpg:
      spring:
        properties:
          hibernate:
            jdbc:
              batch_size: 4
            order_inserts: true
            order_updates: true
```

Is it possible configuring the batch sizes that way? If it is possible, how can I implement this?

Comment: You can set the batch size as max batch size required of two repositories
if the required batch size of ItemRepository is 4 and CarRepository is 6, the batch size can be given as 6.Then it works for both repositories.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It would be a great approach when 2 different batch sizes are required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically you can try to implement [BatchBuilder](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/batch/spi/BatchBuilder.html) interface for example in the following way:

```java
import java.util.Map;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BasicBatchKey;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchBuilderMXBean;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.spi.Batch;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.spi.BatchBuilder;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.spi.BatchKey;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.JdbcCoordinator;
import org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationHelper;
import org.hibernate.service.spi.Configurable;
import org.hibernate.service.spi.Manageable;


public class MyBatchBuilder implements BatchBuilder, Configurable, Manageable, BatchBuilderMXBean
{
   private int jdbcBatchSize;
   
   public MyBatchBuilder()
   {
   }
   
   public MyBatchBuilder(int jdbcBatchSize) {
      this.jdbcBatchSize = jdbcBatchSize;
   }

   @Override
   public void configure(Map configurationValues) {
      jdbcBatchSize = ConfigurationHelper.getInt( Environment.STATEMENT_BATCH_SIZE, configurationValues, jdbcBatchSize );
   }

   @Override
   public int getJdbcBatchSize() {
      return jdbcBatchSize;
   }

   @Override
   public void setJdbcBatchSize(int jdbcBatchSize) {
      this.jdbcBatchSize = jdbcBatchSize;
   }
   
   @Override
   public Batch buildBatch(BatchKey key, JdbcCoordinator jdbcCoordinator)
   {
      final Integer sessionJdbcBatchSize = jdbcCoordinator.getJdbcSessionOwner()
            .getJdbcBatchSize();
      final int jdbcBatchSizeToUse = sessionJdbcBatchSize == null ?
            this.jdbcBatchSize :
            sessionJdbcBatchSize;

      // getEntityName() + "#DELETE"
      // getEntityName() + "#UPDATE"
      BasicBatchKey insertCarBatchKey = new BasicBatchKey("com.your.entities.Car#INSERT", null);
      final int jdbcBatchSizeForCar = 20;
      if (insertCarBatchKey.equals(key))
      {
         return new BatchingBatch( key, jdbcCoordinator, jdbcBatchSizeForCar );
      }

      return new BatchingBatch( key, jdbcCoordinator, jdbcBatchSizeToUse );
   }
}
```

and then add the following properties to your spring application config:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch.builder=com.your.app.MyBatchBuilder
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=4
```

But as it's stated in the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch-jdbcbatch), it is almost never a good idea to switch from Hibernate’s default implementation. So, maybe suggested in the comment approach will be more preferable for your needs.

P.S. Also as it's stated in the hibernate documentation:

> Since version 5.2, Hibernate allows overriding the global JDBC batch size given by the `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` configuration property on a per `Session` basis.

```java
entityManager
    .unwrap( Session.class )
    .setJdbcBatchSize( 10 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the way suggested in the comment approach is great when only 2 different batch sizes are required. However, when the number is increased, your answer should be followed.